# Web3.py EventFilter.get_new_entries() always empty

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

I've following code to obtain new event entries. The idea is to get latest Transfer events from a specific contract.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import json

abi = json.load(open('abi.json'))
address = '0x.....................'

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi,address=address)

event_filter = contract.eventFilter('Transfer',{'fromBlock':0,'toBlock':'latest'})

logs = event_filter.get_new_entries()

print(logs);
```

There is a local ethereum node running under port 8545 with --rpc.

When I run above script after initiating a transaction, it always prints an empty array.

If I change it to `event_filter.get_all_entries()` I can see all the transactions. But `get_new_entries()` doesn't work.
Any idea what would be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I change it to `event_filter.get_all_entries()` I can see all the
>   transactions. But `get_new_entries()` doesn't work. Any idea what would
>   be the issue?

As I can see from [web3.py latest documentation](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

---

The function `LogFilter.get_all_entries()` is returning all logs which match the filter

> Logs will be retrieved using the `web3.eth.Eth.getFilterLogs()` which
>   returns all logs that match the given filter.

---

From the other side we have `LogFilter.get_new_entries()` which returns only new entries since the last poll.

> Logs will be retrieved using the `web3.eth.Eth.getFilterChanges()` which
>   returns only new entries since the last poll.

---

### Summarizing.

If you haven't called this method before, it cannot decide which entries are new, so it returns `undefined`. You should first call `LogFilter.get_all_entries()` and only after you called it and some changes happened call `LogFilter.get_new_entries()`.

> Returns all new entries which occurred **since the last call** to this
>   method for the given `filter_id`

---

[Event Log Filters](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#event-log-filters)