# Strange result for w3.eth.filter({'fromBlock': 2500000, 'toBlock': 'latest'})?

Tags: parity, web3.py

I use
Parity:

> Parity-Ethereum//v2.2.7-stable-b00a21f-20190115/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.31.1

I tried code to see new entries for block range.

```
l = w3.eth.filter({'fromBlock': 2500000, 'toBlock': 'latest'})
l = l.get_new_entries()
print(l)
```

But the result was only for latest block:

```
[{
  'address': '0x3b7c7C457D3aAe04a4631E4888AeEEDd08B24e41',
  'blockHash': HexBytes('0x22faa2d5102d8685b1d5dadc5a52680c8f3e461bf7615e06002f4740c17c0be2'),
  'blockNumber': 2904310,
  'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf23c7f4',
  'logIndex': 0,
  'removed': False,
  'topics': [HexBytes('0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'), HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000000360d2b7d240ec0643b6d819ba81a09e40e5bcd'), HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000081bfb6a2db736c5ec06ddf4654478cf78b3e0be7')],
  'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x878e023cbd496692705f75146fa8f693a9590ff782cfccbab493e057a51d6286'),
  'transactionIndex': 0,
  'transactionLogIndex': '0x0',
  'type': 'mined'
}, {
  'address': '0x81BfB6A2Db736c5EC06DdF4654478CF78B3E0bE7',
  'blockHash': HexBytes('0x22faa2d5102d8685b1d5dadc5a52680c8f3e461bf7615e06002f4740c17c0be2'),
  'blockNumber': 2904310,
  'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000151ce',
  'logIndex': 1,
  'removed': False,
  'topics': [HexBytes('0xcea04943b36b38f541b87028ed4da18dded81fd7741867c8320734d24b5b0ece')],
  'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x878e023cbd496692705f75146fa8f693a9590ff782cfccbab493e057a51d6286'),
  'transactionIndex': 0,
  'transactionLogIndex': '0x1',
  'type': 'mined'
}]
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe this helps, I had the same issue with web3js when using getPastLogs, solved it by passing the 'fromBlock' as a string instead of a number (i.e, '2500000')

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `get_all_entries` instead of `get_new_entries`? The former returns all entries matching the filter, but the later only returns entries since the last poll. Check out [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36009/web3-py-eventfilter-get-new-entries-always-empty) and [the documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html) for more information.